# How can i count the number coming in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can i count the number coming in the number column in excel like as below table. if comes first time then 1, if coming 2nd time then 2 and coming third times then 3 as so on.......

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a running count. In Excel it's specified as: 
`=COUNTIF($A$1:A1;A1)`